# Download a large XML file from an external source in the background, with the ability to resume download if incomplete

Tags: php, file, curl, stream

### Some background information

The files I would like to download is kept at the external server for a week, and a new XML file(10-50mb large) is created there every hour with a different name. I would like the large file to be downloaded to my server chunk by chunk in the background each time my website is loaded, perhaps 0.5mb each time, and then resume the download the next time someone else loads the website. This would require my site to have atleast 100 pageloads each hour to stay updated, so perhaps abit more of the file each time if possible. I have researched **simpleXML**, **XMLreader**, **SAX parsing**, but whatever I do, it seems it takes too long to parse the file directly, therefore I would like a different approach, namely downloading it like described above.

If I download a 30mb **large XML file**, I can parse it locally with XMLreader in 3 seconds(250k iterations) only, but when I try to do the same from the external server limiting it to 50k iterations, it uses 15secs to read that small part, so it would not be possible to parse it directly from that server it seems.

### Possible solutions

I think it's best to use **cURL**. But then again, perhaps **fopen()**, **fsockopen()**, **copy()** or **file_get_contents()** are the way to go. I'm looking for advice on what functions to use to make this happen, or different solutions on how I can parse a 50mb external XML file into a **mySQL** database.

I suspect a **Cron** job every hour would be the best solution, but I am not sure how well that would be supported by webhosting companies, and I have no clue how to do something like that. But if thats the best solution, and the majority thinks so, I will have to do my research in that area too.

If a **java applet/javascript** running in the background would be a better solution, please point me in the right direction when it comes to functions/methods/libraries there aswell.

## Summary

- What's the best solution to downloading parts of a file in the
  background, and resume the download each time my website is loaded
  until its completed?
- If the above solution would be moronic to even try, what
  language/software would you use to achieve the same thing(download a large file every hour)?

Thanks in advance for all answers, and sorry for the long story/question.

Edit: I ended up using this solution to get the files with cron job scheduling a php script. It checks my folder for what files I already have, generates a list of the possible downloads for the last four days, then downloads the next XMLfile in line.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
$current_time = $date->getTimestamp();
$four_days_ago = $current_time-345600;

echo 'Downloading: '."\n";
for ($i=$four_days_ago; $i<=$current_time; ) {
    $date->setTimestamp($i);

    if($date->format('H') !== '00') {
        $temp_filename = $date->format('Y_m_d_H') ."_full.xml";
        if(!glob($temp_filename)) {
            $temp_url = 'http://www.external-site-example.com/'.$date->format('Y/m/d/H') .".xml";
            echo $temp_filename.' --- '.$temp_url.'<br>'."\n";
            break; // with a break here, this loop will only return the next file you should download
        }
    }
    $i += 3600;
}

set_time_limit(300);
$Start = getTime(); 

$objInputStream = fopen($temp_url, "rb");
$objTempStream = fopen($temp_filename, "w+b");

stream_copy_to_stream($objInputStream, $objTempStream, (1024*200000));

$End = getTime();
echo '<br>It took '.number_format(($End - $Start),2).' secs to download "'.$temp_filename.'".';

function getTime() {
    $a = explode (' ',microtime());
    return(double) $a[0] + $a[1];
}
?>
```

edit2: I just wanted to inform you that there is a way to do what I asked, only it would'nt work in my case. With the amount of data I need the website would have to have 400+ visitors an hour for it to work properly. But with smaller amounts of data there are some options; http://www.google.no/search?q=poormanscron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a scheduled, offline task (e.g., cronjob).  The solution you are pursuing is just plain wrong.

The simplest thing that could possibly work is a php script you run every hour (scheduled via cron, most likely) that downloads the file and processes it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I was afraid of that. I were really hoping for a php solution that would let me read e.g. the first 200k bytes first, and the next time it would read from byte 200 001 to 400 000, etc, etc. But, if a cron scheduled php script every hour is the best solution, then I guess I just gotta go shopping for a hosting service where they can provide such a thing. Silly how I can download a file to my own computer via the browser within seconds, but when a php script does it, it takes 1-2minutes. There are definitly room for improvement with PHP if thats truely the case.

Comment: After some minor research into Cron jobs, I realize this is the way to go. Thanks for a very helpful tip. I wish I had rep/points enough to rate this answer, but sadly I do not have that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could try fopen:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/test.xml", "rb");
$contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This script returned 211754 bytes, and that was all. And it took 18.41 secs to execute. I'm not sure if "echo $contents;" was the right way to test the output, so any additional info is appreciated.